# cursor que reciba un parámetro de entrada para obtener campos de 3 tablas relacionadas, 2 campos por cada tabla para un valor de parámetro específico

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

entre tablas personas(id, nombre), usuarios(id_usuarios, id_colaborador), clientes(id_clientes, id_personas), boletas(id_colaborador, id_boletas), colaboradores(id_personas, id_colaborador)

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Cuál es la lógica? ¿Qué has intentado? Los cursores no reciben parámetros.

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.